# How to build "many-hot" in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to combine three columns of categorical data into a single set of binary category-named columns. This is similar to a "one-hot" but the source rows have up to three categories instead of just one. Also, note that there are 100+ categories and I will not know them beforehand.

```
id, fruit1, fruit2, fruit3
1, apple, orange,
2, orange, , 
3, banana, apple,
```

should generate...

```
id, apple, banana, orange
1, 1, 0, 1
2, 0, 0, 1
3, 1, 1, 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to combine all the fruit columns into one column, and the use [`pd.crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) to create a frequency table:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data')
df = df.replace(r' ', np.nan)
#    id   fruit1   fruit2   fruit3
# 0   1    apple   orange      NaN
# 1   2   orange      NaN      NaN
# 2   3   banana    apple      NaN

melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id'])
result = pd.crosstab(melted['id'], melted['value'])
print(result)
```

yields

```
value   apple   banana   orange
id                             
1           1        0        1
2           0        0        1
3           1        1        0
```

---

Explanation: The melted DataFrame looks like this:

```
In [148]:  melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id']); melted
Out[149]: 
   id variable    value
0   1   fruit1    apple
1   2   fruit1   orange
2   3   fruit1   banana
3   1   fruit2   orange
4   2   fruit2      NaN
5   3   fruit2    apple
6   1   fruit3      NaN
7   2   fruit3      NaN
8   3   fruit3      NaN
```

We can ignore the `variable` column; it is the `id` and `value` which is important.
`pd.crosstab` can be used to create a frequency table with `melted['id']` values in the index and `melted['value']` values as the columns:

```
In [150]: pd.crosstab(melted['id'], melted['value'])
Out[150]: 
value   apple   banana   orange
id                             
1           1        0        1
2           0        0        1
3           1        1        0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply value counts to each row:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'fruit1': ['Apple', 'Banana', np.nan],
    'fruit2': ['Banana', np.nan, 'Apple'],
    'fruit3': ['Grape', np.nan, np.nan],
    })

df = df.apply(lambda row: row.value_counts(), axis=1).fillna(0).applymap(int)
```

Before:

```
   fruit1  fruit2 fruit3
0   Apple  Banana  Grape
1  Banana     NaN    NaN
2     NaN   Apple    NaN
```

After:

```
   Apple  Banana  Grape
0      1       1      1
1      0       1      0
2      1       0      0
```